# unable to adjust elements according to screen in swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to adjust elements based on screen sizes. .for example for the car I used a frame for image and set its width and height

```
.frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.6, height:geometry.size.width * 0.6*2.094)
```

0.6 because I want its width to be 0.6 times that of the screen width. and multiplied 2.094 to height because original image height is 2.094 times that of width. and I also set the image position as

```
.position(x: geometry.size.width - geometry.size.width * 0.68, y: geometry.size.height - geometry.size.height*0.38 )
```

But as you can see that the spacing from the bottom is less on small screen than a large screen. Geometry reader has width and height same as that of the screen.

My questions are:

1. Shouldn't the spacing from the bottom be concurrent in all screens as I'm setting the image width, height as well as position w.r.t. the screen dimensions?
2. I used `width: geometry.size.width * 0.6` because I wanted image width to be 60% of screen width. Is there any better approach to solve this problem?

The code:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack{
           
                Image("TeslaCar")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.6, height:geometry.size.width * 0.6*2.094)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width - geometry.size.width * 0.68, y: geometry.size.height - geometry.size.height*0.38 )
            }
        .frame(width: screen.width, height: screen.height)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is because safe-area on different devices is different. You set ignore safe area for external container but not for image. And in general I would avoid such manual positioning.

Comment: @Asperi can you please explain more about manual positioning where I used it?